# can i get source mac address of packet using ngrep?

Tags: ngrep

I want to get the source mac address of the packet, so is it possible to get it using ngrep command ? or is there any way using which i can get mac adresses ,IP addresses and the files getting accessed along with used port again method used like GET or POST.